# OkHttp3: SSL certificate not recognized as valid certificate

Tags: android, security, ssl, okhttp

I'm using `Retrofit2` with `RxJava2` and `OkHttp3` to make an `HTTPS` call to an internal server for testing a `SSL` certificate, but I always get an exception stating:

`HTTP FAILED: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.`

According to the [Google developer documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl.html#CommonProblems), there are 3 reasons why this might occur (unknown CA, self signed certificate or server configuration is missing intermediate CA)

I cannot post the URL, as it is an internal testing server, but opening the URL in a browser on my computer or on my phone in Chrome works fine, this is what I can see from the certificate:

[image]

Therefore I think that it can't be option 1, because the browser recognises the certificate, only my app and OkHttp don't seem so and as it is no self signed certificate, option 2 also shouldn't be the cause.

And this is how my `OkHttp` client is provided by `Dagger`:

```
@Provides
@PerApplication
OkHttpClient provideOkHttpClient(@ApplicationContext Context context) {
    int cacheSize = 10 * 1024 * 1024; // 10 MiB

    File cacheDirectory = new File(context.getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath(), "HttpCache");

    ConnectionSpec spec = new ConnectionSpec.Builder(ConnectionSpec.MODERN_TLS)
            .tlsVersions(TlsVersion.TLS_1_2)
            .cipherSuites(
                    CipherSuite.TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
                    CipherSuite.TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
                    CipherSuite.TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256)
            .build();

    OkHttpClient.Builder httpClientBuilder = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .connectionSpecs(Collections.singletonList(spec))
            .readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .connectTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .cache(new Cache(cacheDirectory, cacheSize));

    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
        HttpLoggingInterceptor loggingInterceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        loggingInterceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
        httpClientBuilder.addInterceptor(loggingInterceptor);
    }

    return httpClientBuilder.build();
}
```

I added the `CollectionSpec` to define that I'm using TLS 1.2, but this makes no difference, I still receive the Trust anchor error.

Is there something else that I need to set in order to use the ssl certificate? Any ideas why the certificate is not accepted?

Comment: "Therefore I think that it can't be option 1, because the browser recognises the certificate" -- I would not assume that what Chrome accepts matches what Android SDK apps will accept in terms of a root certificate authority.

Comment: You're right, that makes sense.

Comment: @Eve I faced the same and have answered http://stackoverflow.com/a/42392679/2870088.  It is option 3 Missing intermediate certificate authority. Yes, browsers will cache intermediate certificates, and use them between different sites. Because of that, if you are missing the intermediate certificate, random users will receive a trust error, while others won't.  http://superuser.com/questions/351516/do-intermediate-certificates-get-cached-in-firefox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem solved itself, the URL of the server was not correct.